# Use jq to append value of one key to another key, but at a different level of document tree

Tags: json, key, jq

I want to output this entire JSON file to a new file but with the value of `filter-values` appended as a string to each `description` of the `filter` item in each `parameters` array.

Some notes:

- I am only interested in the `foo` objects
- Not all `foo` objects contain `parameter` arrays
- Not all `parameter` arrays contain filter objects

```json
{
  "empty": {},
  "paths": {
    "somepath": {
      "foo": {
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "page"
          },
          {
            "name": "sort"
          },
          {
            "name": "filter",
            "description": "This is the `filter` param."
          },
          {
            "name": "orderby",
            "description": "This is the `orderby` param."
          }
        ],
        "filter-values": [
          "1",
          "2",
          "3"
        ],
        "orderby-values": [
          "a",
          "b",
          "c"
        ]
      },
      "bar": {}
    },
    "anotherpath": {
      "foo": {
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "page"
          },
          {
            "name": "filter",
            "description": "This is the `filter` param."
          }
        ],
        "filter-values": [
          "4",
          "5",
          "6"
        ]
      }
    },
    "yetanotherpath": {
      "foo": {
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "page"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the closest I have come to getting it to work:

```
(.paths[].foo."filter-values" // empty | join(", ")) as $filters 
| (.paths[].foo.parameters // empty 
| . [] 
| select(.name? == "filter")).description |= . + " Possible values are: " + $filters
```

Expected output:

```json
{
  "empty": {},
  "paths": {
    "somepath": {
      "foo": {
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "page"
          },
          {
            "name": "sort"
          },
          {
            "name": "filter",
            "description": "This is the `filter` param. Possible values are: 1, 2, 3"
          },
          {
            "name": "orderby",
            "description": "This is the `orderby` param."
          }
        ],
        "filter-values": [
          "1",
          "2",
          "3"
        ],
        "orderby-values": [
          "a",
          "b",
          "c"
        ]
      },
      "bar": {}
    },
    "anotherpath": {
      "foo": {
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "page"
          },
          {
            "name": "filter",
            "description": "This is the `filter` param. Possible values are: 4, 5, 6"
          }
        ],
        "filter-values": [
          "4",
          "5",
          "6"
        ]
      }
    },
    "yetanotherpath": {
      "foo": {
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "page"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Actual output (the entire document is produced twice, with the wrong `filter-values` appended to the `description` in some cases):

```json
{
  "empty": {},
  "paths": {
    "somepath": {
      "foo": {
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "page"
          },
          {
            "name": "sort"
          },
          {
            "name": "filter",
            "description": "This is the `filter` param. Possible values are: 1, 2, 3"
          },
          {
            "name": "orderby",
            "description": "This is the `orderby` param."
          }
        ],
        "filter-values": [
          "1",
          "2",
          "3"
        ],
        "orderby-values": [
          "a",
          "b",
          "c"
        ]
      },
      "bar": {}
    },
    "anotherpath": {
      "foo": {
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "page"
          },
          {
            "name": "filter",
            "description": "This is the `filter` param. Possible values are: 1, 2, 3" 
          }
        ],
        "filter-values": [
          "4",
          "5",
          "6"
        ]
      }
    },
    "yetanotherpath": {
      "foo": {
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "page"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
{
  "empty": {},
  "paths": {
    "somepath": {
      "foo": {
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "page"
          },
          {
            "name": "sort"
          },
          {
            "name": "filter",
            "description": "This is the `filter` param. Possible values are: 4, 5, 6"
          },
          {
            "name": "orderby",
            "description": "This is the `orderby` param."
          }
        ],
        "filter-values": [
          "1",
          "2",
          "3"
        ],
        "orderby-values": [
          "a",
          "b",
          "c"
        ]
      },
      "bar": {}
    },
    "anotherpath": {
      "foo": {
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "page"
          },
          {
            "name": "filter",
            "description": "This is the `filter` param. Possible values are: 4, 5, 6"
          }
        ],
        "filter-values": [
          "4",
          "5",
          "6"
        ]
      }
    },
    "yetanotherpath": {
      "foo": {
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "page"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this do what you want?

```bash
(.paths[].foo | select(all(has("parameters", "filter-values"); .))) |= (
  (.parameters[] | select(.name == "filter").description) +=
    " Possible values are: \(."filter-values" | join(", "))"
)
```

```json
{
  "empty": {},
  "paths": {
    "somepath": {
      "foo": {
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "page"
          },
          {
            "name": "sort"
          },
          {
            "name": "filter",
            "description": "This is the `filter` param. Possible values are: 1, 2, 3"
          },
          {
            "name": "orderby",
            "description": "This is the `orderby` param."
          }
        ],
        "filter-values": [
          "1",
          "2",
          "3"
        ],
        "orderby-values": [
          "a",
          "b",
          "c"
        ]
      },
      "bar": {}
    },
    "anotherpath": {
      "foo": {
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "page"
          },
          {
            "name": "filter",
            "description": "This is the `filter` param. Possible values are: 4, 5, 6"
          }
        ],
        "filter-values": [
          "4",
          "5",
          "6"
        ]
      }
    },
    "yetanotherpath": {
      "foo": {
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "page"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/KE1qX6VIitx)

Comment: This is excellent, @pmf, thank you. However, my original input omitted the scenario where the `.foo.parameters[]` array does not include a param named `filter`. I have fixed that in my original post now. 

With that change, your jq command returns "Cannot iterate over null (null)".

The `has()` method handles the presence of a particular key. How do I look for a key with a particular value?

Comment: @DocGuy The missing `filter` does not pose a problem as it will simply not get selected. But with it also `filter-values` is missing, which leads to the error. So, just add that criterion to the first `select`. Either verbosely using `and` as in `has("parameters") and has("filter-values")`. Or more concisely with the general logical conjunction `all` as in `all(has("parameters", "filter-values"); .)`. I edited my answer using the latter.